# To Assign Equivalent Page No With Particular Party Name Issue ?I need to implement this logic into spread grid tools(Get Row Page Breaks Event)

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops, for-loop, logic

```
Public Class Form1
 Dim mpagecount As New List(Of String)
 Dim mledger As New List(Of String)
 'Dim xpageno As Integer = 8
 Dim xpageno As Integer = 0
 Dim xTempLedger As String


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    mpagecount.Add(2)
    mpagecount.Add(3)
    mpagecount.Add(5)
    mpagecount.Add(7)

    mledger.Add("mohamed")
    mledger.Add("saleem")
    mledger.Add("thameem")
    mledger.Add("irfan")

    For j As Integer = 0 To mpagecount.Count - 1
        ListBox1.Items.Add(mpagecount.Item(j))
        ListBox2.Items.Add(mledger.Item(j))
    Next

    For xtest As Integer = 1 To 8
        ListBox3.Items.Add(xtest)
        If xpageno < mpagecount.Count Then
            xTempLedger = (mledger.Item(xpageno))
            If xtest = mpagecount(xpageno) Then
                ListBox4.Items.Add(mledger.Item(xpageno))
                xpageno += 1
            Else
                ListBox4.Items.Add(xTempLedger)
            End If
        End If
    Next

 End Sub
End Class
```

Output

[image]

Expected Out put is
[image]

Answer (score 0):

At Last I found a solution for that problem

```
  For i As Integer = 1 To 7
        ListBox3.Items.Add(i)
        If i = 1 Then
            ListBox4.Items.Add(mledger.Item(xpageno))
            xpageno += 1
        End If
        If i = mpagecount.Item(xpageno) Then
            ListBox4.Items.Add(mledger.Item(xpageno))
            xpageno += 1
        Else
            If i <> 1 Then
                ListBox4.Items.Add(mledger.Item(xpageno - 1))
            End If
        End If

    Next
```